# Why is the push_back method of vector not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, sfml

I want to put in some elements in a vector.
Till date I have always used this way of inserting elements in the vector and it has always worked. I do not know why it is not working today.

```
World::World()
{
    collisionmap.loadFromFile("collisionmap.png");
    for(int i=0; i<collisionmap.getSize().y; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<collisionmap.getSize().x; j++)
        {
            if(collisionmap.getPixel(j,i)==sf::Color(0,0,0))
            {
                  cout<<"test"<<endl //prints perfectly
                  collisionList.push_back(sf::FloatRect(j*32, i*32, 32, 32));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<collisionList.size(); //shows nothing
}
```

Edit:

*I forgot to mention :-*

1.I am using SFML.

2.**collisionList** is the vector.

3.This code compiles without any problem.

4.The size of the collisionmap is not zero since **collisionmap.getSize()** returns accurate value.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug your code when it doesn't compile or run: http://ideone.com/S5p9EH

Comment: You should really mention that you're using SFML.

Comment: What is `collisionList`? What are those sizes? Perhaps a debugger might help

Comment: Your problem description, "it is not working today", is not helpful. Does it compile. Does it crash? What happens? What do you expect? What do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: So use the debugger. Guess the sizes are zero. Therefore problems loading the file (wrong filename/directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<collisionList.size(); //shows nothing
```

Of course. This just puts stuff in the buffer, It doesn't actually output anything. Try:

```
cout<<collisionList.size()<<endl;
```

Comment: It worked. So the vector wasnt actually empty. But why wasn't it printing before ?

Comment: You had no code to cause it to print. You just put something in the buffer and then never flushed the buffer to output. Computers do exactly what you tell them to do.

Comment: so putting endl at the end of cout flushes the buffer?

Comment: (And if the issue was the vector being empty, wouldn't it have output `0`?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, I do not exactly know what the question is about, but how could putting `endl` make it work? 90% time I use only `cout << "something"` does it mean it the compiler is flushing the buffer for me?? And it might fail anytime, just like here?

Comment: @user007 You have some other code somewhere that flushes the buffer. If you paste an example, I can point you to it. It may be the destructor.

Comment: Well, if I simply have a "Hello World!" program without an `endl`

Comment: Then the destructor of `cout` destroys the buffer. A non-existing buffer can't buffer anything.

Comment: And why doesn't the destructor of `cout` flush the buffer above?

Comment: @Raj Brother, can you please post the code once? Just copy pasting on ideone, won't take much time! Hope it's not too big! :D

Comment: Well it is basically the constructor of a class called 'World'.  In this constructor I created the vector. The class' object is created in the 'main' method. Nothing more to add to the above code.

Comment: `endl` is equivalent to a `newline` + `flush` operation. So anything in the buffer is printed to the `stdout` (in your case). Referring from `C++ primer 5th edition by Stanley B Lippman`, "The operating system might store the data in a buffer to be printed later. Using a buffer allows the operating system to combine several output operations from our program into a single system-level write. Because writing to a device can be time-consuming.". Bottom line, `cout` might lead to the data being stored in the buffer.  `endl` flushes it anyway.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz @bk2dcradle http://ideone.com/2k4apx If I have this code the destructor of `cout` won't be called until the `operator` function is exited!(I believe) But, when I run it on my machine it prints all the numbers immediately and then waits for 5s! I don't think the for loop flushes the buffer, does it?? `_sleep` is probably depricated that is why it gives error on ideone! Please replace it with a suitable pause function!

Comment: Can you please use `usleep(1000000)`  (header `unistd.h`) and run the code on your machine again? The same code as yours, but using `unistd.h` and `usleep`, first sleeps for a few seconds then prints all the numbers. [Code](http://ideone.com/uSWGsH)

Comment: Didn't work! But I got your point! Probably some optimizations or stuff, due which it doesn't work on my machine. @bk2dcradle Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. If you ever feel that you don't want to store any data in the buffer and want to print directly to a device, use `unitbuf` like so `cout<<unitbuf;`,  `unitbuf` is a `manipulator`. Example: Just put this line, `cout<<unitbuf;` as the first line in `main()` and `cout` will print directly to stdout. No data will be stored in the buffer.